# QGIS 3.2 using a USGS Topo for a basemap

Tags: qgis, basemap, usgs

On QGIS 3.2 I add, through the XYZ Tiles tab in the browser, this URL:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}.jpg

All that is displayed when it is added as a layer is a page of postage stamp size (5x5) pictures of the entire world. Moving or zooming simply refreshes the same view of a 5x5 squares of the world. I've tried this a number of ways and all FAIL. Any suggestions would be helpful.

The goal is to have USGS Topo Maps as a base map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify each of the ways you have tried, and the exact details about how each failed.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try loading it as a WMTS layer? In the Data Source Manager, use the WMS/WMTS tab to set it up. Or choose Layer->Add Layer->Add WMS/WMTS Layer. Use the following URL:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: I did and that worked. Strangly when I add the same thing through the XYZ Tile layer it did not work. Thank you for your excellent help.

Comment: Happy to hear it! Feel free to upvote or accept any of the answers that have helped you. :)

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted both answers, but I don't yet have enough reputation points for my upvote to show up. Both were timely and useful and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This URL worked for me:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}

Tile server connection properties:

[image]

The added layer:

[image]

Comment: http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}
Works for me also. I added it thru the XYZ Tiles tab in the Browser. I was trying $(x} and x={x} and did not use type=xyz&url=http.... This time, I just used your exact link above and it came up quickly. Do you know if and how to parameterize the request, say, to start at a certain viewpoint?

Have any ideas on how to do the Historic Topos?

Thank you very much. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin. Just type `USA` in search field. It will create XYZ provider for you.

[image]